# Virtualizing OSX partition on MacBook running Linux

Tags: linux, osx, virtual-machine

I have a Macbook Pro with a partitioned drive that hosts Arch linux and OSX. Linux is my main development environment but occasionally a need arises to test some code on OSX. This doesn't happen often. It makes me think that, rather than dual booting, I can point some sort of virtualization software at the OSX partition and boot it up.

The question is, what sort of software (preferably free) would allow me to boot up OSX in a VM? Are there any pitfalls that I should avoid with this setup?

Answer (score 1):

I have gone down [this](http://www.macbreaker.com/2014/05/os-x-mavericks-in-virtualbox-with-niresh.html) route before in a similar setup using VirtualBox. It works, though I'd caution you. The osx desktop is very gpu dependent, and VirtualBox (at least at that time) did not have great gpu support, leaving me with a virtualized osx desktop with very stunted performance.

YMMV, just one datapoint.

Comment: I am fine with OSX being visually stunted. The code I develop does not require anymore more than a terminal and, with luck, I'd probably set up ssh on OSX so that I can use Linux all the time.